# Pirate English Showing on FaceBook LikeBox

Tags: facebook

I changed my language to Pirate English a couple weeks ago for fun - something that shows up just for me when I experience FaceBook. Now my FaceBook PAGE LikeBox is showing up in Pirate English for everyone that sees it. I tried changing my language to regular English, clearing cookies, changing the LikeBox code, etc. but nothing clears it out. ARRRR! Now everyone sees "Spy fer us o'er on Ye Olde Facebook" when they go to my website and see the LikeBox for my FaceBook page... Question...

Does anyone know how to fix this?

My guess is that it is a bug in FaceBook. My personal language settings are not supposed to affect what what everyone else sees, and even if this was what happened, changing it back to regular English should have fixed it. I am guessing that it will clear up at some point, but it is a bit embarrassing with FANs being called "scallywags" - ARRR!

Befriend a Matey! Me care not fer such triflins an' need fixrins from Ye an' thar scurvy dogs! Back ta plunderin' an' me scrawlin's whilst ah whit fer' em!